# Things to consider before reinstalling snow leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, installation

Prior to do Snow Leopard clean re-install, I have already done following pre-tasks.

1. Time Machine backup of my personal files.
2. Safari bookmarks backup
3. Address book backup
4. No backup for iCal (Google) and iPhoto (Picasa) because there are in the cloud.
5. iTunes media folder backup
6. Keychain files backup

Is there any other things to consider?

Please advise me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing else. If you've done a full backup like that, especially Time Machine, you're good to go. If you're feeling twitchy still, do an `/Applications` and `/Library` backup as well.

Comment: Just for reference, I did a hard drive replacement yesterday in a white Intel iMac, and OS X 10.4 (Tiger). While I was dreaming of Time Machine, I managed to get away with just the user folder, `/Applications` and `/Library`. The owner is beyond happy with the results.